# Trying to run this in Oracle 8i

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle8i

I'm trying to run this query in Oracle 8i but it's not working!

```
SELECT DECODE(seqnum, 1, t.ID1,cnt,'0') PI_VALUE1,
  DECODE(seqnum, 1, t.STARTTIME,cnt,t.ENDTIME) timestamp,
  '090.'
  || t2.APP
  || '.BATCH' tagname
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
    row_number() over(partition BY t.ID1, t.PLANT_UNIT order by t.STARTTIME) AS seqnum,
    COUNT(*) over(partition BY t.ID1, t.PLANT_UNIT) cnt
  FROM tb_steps t
  ) t
INNER JOIN tb_equipments t2
ON t2.plant_unit = t.plant_unit
WHERE (seqnum    = 1
OR SEQNUM        = CNT)
AND (T.STARTTIME  > '15-jul-2013'
AND t.ENDTIME    < '15-aug-2013') ;
```

I've already made a lot of changes [like changing `case when` for `decode`] but it's still not OK...

Can someone help me write the query to be supported by Oracle 8i?

PS.: I know this version is not supported by Oracle for AGES but I'm only querying data for my .NET application so I can't upgrade/touch the DB.

Version is 8.1.7 and the specific error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
```

Many thanks,

Comment: What is the error?  And exactly what version of Oracle are you using?  8i is a marketing label for three major database releases with different functionality.

Comment: Sorry for the vague information. Version is 8.1.7 and the error is ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. [Edited the question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSI joins were not introduced until Oracle Database 9iR1 (9.0.1).  They are not supported in 8.1.7.

Try re-writing the query without an ANSI style join.

Something like this may work:

```
SELECT DECODE(seqnum, 1, t.ID1,cnt,'0') PI_VALUE1,
  DECODE(seqnum, 1, t.STARTTIME,cnt,t.ENDTIME) timestamp,
  '090.'
  || t2.APP
  || '.BATCH' tagname
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
    row_number() over(partition BY t.ID1, t.PLANT_UNIT order by t.STARTTIME) AS seqnum,
    COUNT(*) over(partition BY t.ID1, t.PLANT_UNIT) cnt
  FROM tb_steps t
  ) t, tb_equipments t2
WHERE t2.plant_unit = t.plant_unit
  AND   (t.seqnum    = 1
      or t.seqnum        = t.cnt)
AND (T.STARTTIME  > '15-jul-2013'
AND t.ENDTIME    < '15-aug-2013') ;
```

Totally untested....

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me an example then I can apply it to my query?

Comment: Try that.  Also, depending on the datatype of STARTTIME and ENDTIME, it would be better to explicitly convert the date strings to DATE datatype, if that's what datatype STARTTIME and ENDTIME are.

Comment: Tested right now and it works perfectly! I have more similar queries so I'll apply this changes to them as well. thanks a lot!